# CloudFormation AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment RoleMappings syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

In my AWS CloudFormation stack, I want to attach roles to Cognito identity pool (which works), and for Authentication providers > Cognito > Authenticated role selection, select "Choose role from token" using the CloudFormation syntax (which doesn't work), as followed:

```
    wzjCognitoIdentityPoolRoles:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
      Properties:
        IdentityPoolId:
          Ref: wzjCognitoIdentityPool
        Roles:
          authenticated:
            Fn::GetAtt: [cognitoAuthRoleWithIdentity, Arn]
          unauthenticated:
            Fn::GetAtt: [cognitoAuthRoleNoIdentity, Arn]
        RoleMappings:
          Type: Token
          AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
```

When I deploy, I got the following error:

```
An error occurred: wzjCognitoIdentityPoolRoles - Property validation failure: [Value of property {/RoleMappings/Type} does not match type {Object}, Value of property {/RoleMappings/AmbiguousRoleResolution} does not match type {Object}].
```

But as I understand the [AWS CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-identitypoolroleattachment-rolemapping.html), I think I use the correct syntax.

How can I fix that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should focus on the syntax of `AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment` but not `RoleMappings`.

From [AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-identitypoolroleattachment.html), we can get in `RoleMappings`

> This is a string to RoleMapping object map

So I think you can try:

```
RoleMappings:
  'graph.facebook.com':
      Type: Token
      AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
```

Here `'graph.facebook.com'` is just an example.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that actually. In my case, Cognito is the authentication provider, so according to the doc, I need to use that syntax: cognito-idp-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_abcdefghi:app_client_id.
But I don't know how to create that string using CloudFormation syntax...

Comment: Maybe you can try to replace `'graph.facebook.com'` with `'cognito-idp-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_abcdefghi:app_client_id'`. [AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-identitypoolroleattachment.html) mentions your case.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, but I don't know how to construct that dynamically using CloudFormation or Serverless framework syntax, since it's a key and not a value. And that makes things way more complicated...

Comment: Are your case same as [Cognito IdentityPoolRoleAttachment Role Mappings](https://forum.serverless.com/t/cognito-identitypoolroleattachment-role-mappings/3003)? Maybe [AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment - dynamic RoleMappings?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=783626#783626) can help you...

Comment: @LiuChang the link seems to be broken. Can you tell what was the workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this generated this way:

```
!Join [ "", [ "cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" , "/", !Ref CognitoUserPool, ":", !Ref CognitoUserPoolAppClient], ]
```

Where `CognitoUserPoolAppClient` is of type `AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient`.

I was able to successfully add the rules to Identity provider.